# Exposing contacts and calendar data with own backend

Tags: c#, .net, calendar

Assume you have an encrypted file containing contact and calendar data (in some proprietary format) which can be loaded by some .net application. On a local (Windows) machine, I'd like to make these contacts and calendar entries accessible by clients like Thunderbird or Outlook.

I would prefer not to convert the encrypted data to unencrypted files but rather provide an open port for these applications to connect to, especially as write support (for editing the data) would be nice to have as well.

I was looking around if I could adopt anything from the free groupware implementations but except for OpenMAPI I haven't found anything which was designed for custom backends - and OpenMAPI doesn't seem to exists outside its German Wikipedia article.

Do you know about any code or approaches which would allow to make such data available to client apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one solution I found is to use IronPython and run [Radicale](http://radicale.org/%20Radicale) which allows to use a custom backend.